Question on switching for inductive loads
Quoting from "Sinalda - Inrush Currents | The Use of Static Voltage Stabilisers and Frequency Converters with Inductive Loads":

When you switch on an inductive load, there's a phenomenon known as "inrush current" or "switch-on surge". Here's why this happens:
Initial state: Before the switch is closed, there's no current flowing in the circuit. The inductor's voltage is zero, and it's not storing any energy.
Switch Closure: When the switch is closed, the voltage across the inductor changes instantaneously from zero to the supply voltage. However, due to the property of inductance, the current through the inductor can't change instantaneously. This is due to "Lenz's Law", which states that the current change in an inductor will always act in a direction to oppose the cause of the change. Therefore, the inductor initially acts like a short circuit, and a large current (the inrush current, or switch-on surge) begins to flow.
Steady State: Over time, the inductor current increases as the magnetic field builds up. Once the field is fully established, the, inductor behaves like a normal circuit component with a certain resistance, and the current settles down to its normal steady-state value. This transition period is called the "Transient Response".

I understand that an inductor opposes a change in the current flow, so if you change the voltage by switching to an out of phase source the inductor will try to maintain the original current despite the voltage level of the new source. I don't understand why this causes inrush current, and why resistive loads don't suffer from inrush when switching. I'd also appreciate clarification why "Once the field is fully established, the, inductor behaves like a normal circuit component."

No, the inductor does no initially act as a short circuit.  Where did you get that idea?

Okay. Can someone then please explain what then causes inrush currents when an inductive load is reconnected to an out of phase power source, and why we don't see inrush current with resistive loads? Edit: Referring to your edit - I didn't write the quote, I copied it from the linked source. I was requesting clarification re: the quote.

Turning on a transformer at an arbitrary angle adds a kind of DC component to the AC current. It needs a few cycles until the current integral is close to zero.
